# get column with the same value on the database using codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

Here are my resources first

[image]

As you can see on my database I have a `Referal_Code` and `Referral_Link`

Now what I am trying to here is I want to get all those `Referral_Link` that has the same value on the `Referal_Code`

I know I am no where near to what I am trying to do but I am trying my best really to get this done.
Here what I have tried so far

On my `model`

```
public function get_same_referral_code()
{
   $this->db->select('referal_code');
   $this->db->where('referal_code', 'PoVsw0Epne');
   $query = $this->db->get('investor');
   if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
       foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
       }
       return $data;
    }
}
```

and on my `controller`

```
public function get_all()
{
    $data = array();
    $data['title'] = "Rewards";
    $data["data"] = $this->investor->get_all_investor();
    $data["get_all_flevel"] = $this->investor->get_all_first_level();
    $data["referrals"] = $this->investor->get_same_referral_code();
    $this->template->load('default_layout','contents','rewards',$data);
}
```

and I am calling it on my `view` like this

```
<?php 
    
    echo ($referrals[0][id]);
    echo ($referrals[0][firstname]);
    echo ($referrals[0][referal_code]);
    echo ($referrals[0][referral_link]);
     
?>
```

What my expected result should be like this

[image]

Could someone help me .

## EDIT

I've tried again this way to get what I want .

First I tried to get all the `referal_code`

```
public function get_same_referral_code()
    {
        $this->db->select('referal_code');
        $query = $this->db->get('investor');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

and now I will going to use this method `get_same_referral_code()` to check if
`referral_link` has the same value on the `referal_code`

```
public function get_same_referral_link()
    {
        $this->db->select('referral_link');
        $this->db->where('referral_link','get_same_referral_code();');
        $query = $this->db->get('investor');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            foreach($query->result() as $row)
            {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

but the problem is that I got this error now

> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think sub query will help you

```
$SQL= "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE referal_code EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT Referral_Link FROM tableName)";
$query = $this->db->query($SQL);
return $query->result_array();
```

or

```
$SQL= "SELECT * FROM investor WHERE referral_link IN (SELECT DISTINCT referal_code FROM investor)";
$query = $this->db->query($SQL);
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: Hi sir . I updated my question and there's an edit section .

Comment: i think what you`re doing is same concepts as mine, but your code has higher complexcity. i think using subquery better than you have to make 2 function. why choosing the harder way when you got the esier one.

Comment: So how could I display it on my view sir?

Comment: because if i try `foreach($refs as $g) {echo $g->referal_code;}` i got this error to Message: Trying to get property 'referal_code' of non-object

Comment: first you have to make sure the query has working with tested in db tools like phpmyadmin or heidiSQL. For the view is same like when you display data with result array function. you can use looping in your view like foreach after that you can echo the array that contain your data table.

Comment: and this error occured too You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT referal_code FROM investor)' at line 1

Comment: I guess sir your WHERE referal_code EXISTS is incorrect

Comment: ```SELECT * FROM `investor` WHERE EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT referal_code FROM investor where referral_link = referal_code)``` i tried this instead. But unfortunately its returning nothing

Comment: try this SELECT * FROM `investor` WHERE referral_link EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT referal_code FROM investor)

Comment: or try this SELECT * FROM `investor` WHERE referral_link IN (SELECT DISTINCT referal_code FROM investor)

Comment: one more question sir . Can I have 2 parameters in `SELECT DISTINCT referal_code, firstname` somethingg like that?

Comment: i dont think its gonna work, because clause in/exists need single column to compare, if you want to echo first name you can select in main query not instead of  subquery